# React Native - UI freezes during API calls

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm facing an issue in react native application where the UI freezes if any network requests are in progress. Every time I do a request to API the UI freezes until the request is responded.

React native version: 0.70.6

I'm calling 5 APIs in a screen, and there are some buttons in the screen which has different functionalities like opening the drawer navigator, navigate to other screen etc. The problem is that these button won't respond if we click until all the 5 APIs return response.

I'm calling the APIs in useEffect (initial load)

```
useEffect(()=>{
    getCollaborations();
    getCreatorXP();
    getDeals(0);
    getTrending();
    getProfile();
},[])
```

Comment: Are you using Hermes engine ? If yes could you try with javascriptcore instead. Check this link https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes#switching-back-to-javascriptcore for instructions

Comment: @KarthikSuthan, I tried with javascriptcore.. but still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You have a blocking UI issue, try this:

```
const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
        const collaborationsPromise = getCollaborations();
        const creatorXPPromise = getCreatorXP();
        const dealsPromise = getDeals(0);
        const trendingPromise = getTrending();
        const profilePromise = getProfile();

        await Promise.all([
            collaborationsPromise,
            creatorXPPromise,
            dealsPromise,
            trendingPromise,
            profilePromise,
        ]);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
}, [getCollaborations, getCreatorXP, getDeals, getTrending, getProfile]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [fetchData]);
```

Promise ensures that all API calls are handled concurrently and ensures that no UI is blocked during the process. Use it whenever you need to make multiple API calls at the same time.

Comment: Promise.all will reject even if one api fails.